# When pagedlistholder is used to paginate, why does the pagination content not change at all when current and PageSize change

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
PagedListHolder<UserArticleVo> userAritcleListPage=new PagedListHolder<>(userArticleVoList);
        userAritcleListPage.setPage(current-1);
        userAritcleListPage.setPageSize(10);
        return userAritcleListPage;
```

When currentPage switches to as like as two peas, the page should not display the contents, but the contents of the page are exactly the same as the first page.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've solved,this is the code of the original control layer

```
List<UserArticleVo> articleList = articleListPage.getSource();
```

`getSource()`This method gets the source data, not the paged content

The following method should be used instead

```
List<UserArticleVo> articleList = articleListPage.getPageList();
```